# How do I override the toString method when my object contains an array?

Tags: java, arrays, double, tostring

In my main method I need to print out two objects that are created in a second class. This is my code.

```
public String toString(){

        String z = "";
        for(int i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
            z = z + data[i] + ", ";
        }
        return z;
    }
```

I have a Stat constructor that sets the array data to the array called in the calling object.

```
    public Stat(double[] d){
        double[] data = new double[d.length];
        this.data = data;
```

This is how I initialized data

```
int i=1;
private double[] data = new double[i];
```

This is the calling class

```
public static void main(String[] args){
double[] data = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
Stat statA = new Stat(data);

data[0] = 3.0;
data[1] = 4.0;
data[3] = 5.0;

Stat statB = new Stat(data);
System.out.println("statA data= " + statA.toString());
System.out.println("statB data= " + statB.toString());
```

When I run the debugger the objects contain the correct data values but when I call toString, they both print {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}

Comment: Why do you think the problem is with `toString`?

Comment: FYI: You can shorten your `toString()` to `return String.join(", ", data);` if `data` is a `List<string>` (can be made into a list easily).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's you problem :

```
 public Stat(double[] d){
        double[] data = new double[d.length];
        this.data = data;
```

You create data array which is new d.length size array.
In Java new allocated memory is by default filled with 0's, so that's why you have got printed this in your program.

Change that code, e.x.:

```
public Stat(double[] d){
        this.data = d;
```

Comment: This is mostly correct. However, `this.data` will be a reference to `d`, not a separate array, so when the contents are changed after the `statA` constructor, `statA.data` will be changed. This can obviously be avoided by using a separate array to construct `statA` and `statB`, but it would be better to use `this.data = Arrays.copyOf(d, d.length);` just in case.

Comment: @jonhopkins - that's true, but as you can see in the code,author three times wanted to change value of array element's.
Copying an array will prevent that, that's obvious, becouse of various references. But is that what's author wanted?

Comment: It is certainly possible that changing the data in both objects is what OP wants and expects. In that case, the code can be left as it is (using your changes of course). But I can't think of many cases where that is what is wanted, so I left my first comment as a note on what will actually happen, and if that's not what OP wanted, then it will probably avoid another question later asking why `statA` and `statB` are printing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your

`public Stat(double[] d){
        double[] data = new double[d.length];
        this.data = data;`

is causing the problem as you create a new array of the input array size (`d.length`), hence the array in the class doesn't contain the data. You want something like:

`public Stat(double[] d){
        this.data = d
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `Arrays.toString(statA)` if the instance member data is misplaced.